# Error in ListView android

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview

I have array with size of 50 elements but some things are null so while creating listview it shows error like

```
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-07 06:37:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is my code how i'm creating the listview

```
 String[] summary = new String[5];
    summary = obj.getAllSummary();
    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, summary);     
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My getAllSummary function

```
 private String[] summary = new String[5];  
    //here some function that will set the `summary` array size. i will be        from 0 to 5
    public String[] getAllSummary(){
    return summary;
    }
```

this `summary` array has some field as null. once i want to delete them. i mean i need to create string array dynamically. 
or i should add in listview after checking whether array element whether null or not. how to do this please help me !

Comment: Just a thought - you're declaring an array of size 5, and then immediately use this pointer to point to the array you're returning. so you're creating an array for nothing. Do this instead: ` String[] summary = obj.getAllSummary();`

Comment: yep. but in the getAllSummary function has 5 fields. i might fill 2 or 3 normally. in extreme case 5. so here if i fill 3 elements others will be null. when i return  `String[] summary `size also will be 5. so i need to create array dynamically in `getAllSummary` ho to do this , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String[] getAllSummary(){

        int k=0;
       for(int i=0;i<summary.length;i++){
           if(summary[i]!=null)
          k++;
         }

       String[] summary2 = new String[k];
       for(int i=0;i<summary.length;i++){
           if(summary[i]!=null)
         summary2[i]=summary[i];
         }
      return summary2;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said data items changes dynamically, any time 1 or 2 or 5 etc. so you should use ArrayList insted of String array. in arrayList no need to define size. Depending on the requirement it's size can be increased or decreased.